# Number of different five card hands

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

You are dealt a hand of 5 cards from a standard 52 card deck. You flip one of the cards over and it is the ace of spades. Given this information, how many different five card hands could you have been dealt such that you now have four cards of the same rank?

The two cases for four cards of the same rank in a five card hand are either the ace of spades with 4 cards of the same rank (none of them an ace), or 4 aces with 1 other card, for a total of 12 + 48 = 60 different five hard hands. Is this correct?

Edit: 48 different hands for the 4 aces case.

Comment: "Four aces and one other card" would appear to describe $48$ hands.

Comment: Thats right, thanks for correcting me. Then the answer is 60?

Comment: Yes, I agree with $60$.